# Select all c files except file name or path contains particular string

Tags: python, glob, shutil

I have a folder with many subfolders including zip files. I want to select  .c files if the file path does not contain particular strings.
For example,
exclude file paths containing "abc", "myfiles", "new"
exclude

```
C:\Users\Downloads\All_h_files\abcmln.c
C:\Users\Downloads\All_h_files\myfilesos\mlo.c
C:\Users\Downloads\All_h_files\newfile.c
C:\Users\Downloads\All_h_files\newfile\sso.c
C:\Users\Downloads\All_h_files\nno.c
```

I tried,

```
import os
import shutil
path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\All_h_files\\"
destination_folder = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\All_h"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        destination = destination_folder + '\\' + file
        source = os.path.join(root,file)
        if "new" or "myfiles" or "abc" not in source:
            if(file.endswith(".c")):
                shutil.copy(source, destination)        
print("Files Copied!!!")
```

Not giving the expected result.

Comment: if "new" or "myfiles" or "abc" not in source: is wrond and not evalute to what you expect

Answer (score 0):

change this sentence:

```
if "new" or "myfiles" or "abc" not in source:
```

to

```
if not all([item not in source for item in  ["new", "myfiles", "abc"]]):
```

furthermore you could use the glob package to list the files. like glob.glob(os.path.join(what_ever_pth, '*.c')) to list file with *.c extension.
and use methods like `os.path.join` for constructing paths to ensure the behavior is gonna be correct no matter which os.